# Keyboard Interaction with Numbers in DropDown List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, browser

I've created a simple drop-down list on an ASPX web page.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>01</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>02</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>03</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>04</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>05</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>06</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>07</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>08</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>09</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>13</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>14</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>16</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>17</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>18</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>19</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>21</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>22</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>23</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>24</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>25</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>26</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>27</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>28</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>29</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>31</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

When a drop-down control has focus and the user clicks the numbers on their keyboard/keypad, what "controls" the selection of a number? Is it however the user's browser has chosen to handle it or a web standard or something else?

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: In HTML, it's compared to the value attribute of the option element. So if listItem 10 gets the value attribute 10, pressing 1 on the keyboard will jump to that option element, providing that the item 01 has the value 01 and not the value 1.

Comment: It's a standard browser behaviour, which can not be modified. You are able to override it using `keypress` event with `preventDefault` method call.

Comment: To add a little more info, I'm trying to find out if each browser maker chooses how the selection works or are they trying to go by a usability standard/web standard. If I type 21 fast, it selects 21. If I type 2 wait a second, then click 1, it selects 10 in Chrome and Edge.